# Comparing two Classes using the equality operator

Tags: java

What are the pitfalls of comparing Class instances using the equality operator?

```
boolean compareTypes(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> rootClazz) {
    return clazz == rootClazz;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No *pitfalls* really; it behaves just as you'd expect, if you expect the actual behavior :) Besides, the `equals()` method for `Class` objects is just the inherited one from `Object`, which uses the `==` operator anyway.

The only surprising part is if the same class file is loaded by two different class loaders, you'll get two separate class objects which will compare as `false`. This is by design.

Comment: But, of course, it is fully proper to return `false` if there are two classloaders involved.

Comment: Which is what "this is by design" is meant to imply.

Answer (score 3):

If the classes were loaded by different `ClassLoader`s then the classes may be from the same file, but not represented by the same object. In this situation, they may also have different behaviour, as one of the loaders may have performed bytecode modifications.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pitfalls. `Class` doesn't override the default `Object.equals` so it's the same semantics, except that there actually **would** be a pitfall with using `equals` since the left operand being `null` will provoke an NPE.

Comment: @OrangeDog ...what it says in the answer.

Comment: @OrangeDog he mentioned the pitfall, although not a big pitfall, its still an inconvenience when comparing to using the `==`.  So it is a small pitfall.

Comment: @JonTaylor So it's a pit-**stumble** :)

Comment: @JonTaylor "since the left operand..." wasn't there when I commented

Comment: @OrangeDog It wasn't on your screen maybe, but it was there. I posted and then posted an edit within 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Class does not override equals and extends Object directly, equals and == are the same in this case.

Regardless, best practice is to use equals when you can.

If you don't know the different between == and equals go read about it.

Answer (score -1):

It may be wiser to do

```
boolean compareTypes(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> rootClazz) {
    return clazz.getName().equals(rootClazz.getName());
}
```

or some version of `getName()` such as `getSimpleName()`

Comment: `getSimpleName` will break for identically named classes in different packages.